# Facing a Parse Error while running my app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, development-environment

[I am getting an error-

Parse Error at [row, col]:[1,1]
Message: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.][1]

After running the app the above message is getting displayed .

How should I solve this? It would be very helpful if anyone explains the reason of this error.

I have created two activities and their xml codes are pasted below.

**First Activity- xml file**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.ExampleApp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="left" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="138dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="138dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="114dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="112dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="112dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
        android:text="MY GREAT APP"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/nameInput"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />"

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/createBirthdayButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:onClick="createBirthdayCard"
        android:text="create bday card"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nameInput" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cake"
        android:layout_width="173dp"
        android:layout_height="445dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/createBirthdayButton"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/cake" />;
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Second activity- xml file**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".birthdaygreeting">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="HAPPY BIRTHDAY"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.478"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.481" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error points to [row, col]:[1,1], the first line in the file. The XML declaration is missing from the top on both activity xml files.

To solve this, make sure the xml version and encoding declaration tag is placed above -
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

Comment: I have included the code now. Please check it.

Comment: Also change, />" to /> just after -app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView".

Comment: I have written the XML declaration, please check it carefully. I changed />" to /> now, thank you but still the error persists.